# Issue while using the AVSpeechSynthensizer terminating in the real time devices

Tags: swift, speech-to-text, voice

Iam integrating the dialogflow into my swift file which include the questions displaying in one field named chipresponse and it should output the voice and then the message field will get the input through voice and here is my code and it is terminating.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var messageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chipResponse: UILabel!
    var a_count = 0
    var b_count = 0
    var docRef : DocumentReference!
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var db: Firestore!
    var a = ""
    private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-US"))
    private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    @IBOutlet weak var microphonebutton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        if audioEngine.isRunning
        {
        audioEngine.stop()
        recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {

                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)

            } catch {
                print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
            }

        microphonebutton.isEnabled = false
        microphonebutton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
        messageField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let request = ApiAI.shared().textRequest()
        if let text = self.messageField.text, text != "" {


                if self.a_count == 1
                {

                    print("count",self.a_count)

                }
                let new = uid! + text
                request?.query = new
                print("new",new)


            print("text",text)
        }
        else
        {
            return
        }


        request?.setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess({ (request1, response1) in
            let response1 = response1 as! AIResponse
            if let textResponse1 = response1.result.fulfillment.messages{
                let textRespoArray = textResponse1 [ 0 ] as NSDictionary
                print(textRespoArray.value(forKey: "speech") as! String)
                self.a = textRespoArray.value(forKey: "speech") as! String
                print("a",self.a)
                print("else count",self.a_count)
                if self.messageField.text != "Early years"
                {

                }
                if self.a == "Level 1 completed. Unlocked the next level. Visit the View Your Story section to see your answers."
                {
                    print("ramya")

                    self.messageField.isHidden = true

                }

                if self.a == "Are there any childhood experiences that stand out that you’d like to share"
                {
                    print("In loop")
                    self.a_count = 1
                    print("a count",self.a_count)
                }
                self.speechAndText(text:  textRespoArray.value(forKey: "speech") as! String)
            }
        }, failure: { (request1, error) in
            print(error!)
        })
        ApiAI.shared().enqueue(request)

        messageField.text = ""
        }
        else
        {
            startRecording()
            microphonebutton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
        }
    }



    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    func speechAndText(text: String) {
        let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.chipResponse.text = text
        }, completion: nil)
    }
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       messageField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
       microphonebutton.isEnabled = false  //2
       speechRecognizer!.delegate = self  //3
      SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in  //4
        var isButtonEnabled = false
        switch authStatus {  //5
        case .authorized:
            isButtonEnabled = true
        case .denied:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("User denied access to speech recognition")
        case .restricted:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("Speech recognition restricted on this device")
        case .notDetermined:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("Speech recognition not yet authorized")
        }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
            self.microphonebutton.isEnabled = isButtonEnabled
        }
    }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func startRecording() {
        messageField.text = ""
        if recognitionTask != nil {
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
        }
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }
        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
            fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
        }
        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer!.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
            var isFinal = false
            if result != nil {

                self.messageField.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
            }
            if error != nil || isFinal {
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.recognitionTask = nil
                self.microphonebutton.isEnabled = true
            }
        })
        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
        }
        messageField.text = "Say something, I'm listening!"

    }
}
```

When I use this code the chipresponse text voice is getting too low and then terminating and saying nullptr() - Tap error sometimes and sometimes it shows IFFormat code error

Please help me out,
Thanks